# Type Not Found on SparkFlumeProtocol and EventBatch when building Spark in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark

I've run into a problem trying to build Spark from within the Scala Eclipse IDE, following instructions given in the [Spark Confluence wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools#UsefulDeveloperTools-Eclipse).

Specifically, I encountered "type not found" errors on the on classes `SparkFlumeProtocol` and `EventBatch`.

How can I get past these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It turns out, the above missing classes are present in the Maven target directory for one of the Spark projects:
    `spark-streaming-flume-sink/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/compiled_avro`

To get all to build in Eclipse, you can simply add the above path as an Eclipse source directory for th `spark-streaming-flume-sink` project. (Right-click the project in Project Explorer and select `Build Path` / `Configure Build Path...` / `Source` tab / `Add Folder` and browse to the path.